# Prestashop 1.7 webservice login customer

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How to can I login customer via webservice in Prestashop **1.7**

In Prestashop 1.6(In 1.7 not working):

```
    define('_COOKIE_KEY_', 'OXFQDX3YYM8MJH1RYGAQHH2LX79ZNRX');
    $md5_password = md5(_COOKIE_KEY_+password);
```

> http://yourdomainname.com/api/customers/
>   ?filter[email]=user@yourdomainname.com
>   &filter[passwd]=$md5_password

Comment: Hi, could you share your working code on the login as customer using the webservice? I'm having a lot of trouble with the password verify part. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

check password with PHP:

1) Get customer by email:

> http://domain.com/api/customers?filter[email]=customer@domain.com

2) verify "passwd":

> password_verify(the_input_password, passwd);

PASSWORD_VERIFY DOCS:

> http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php

Comment: This isn't the complete version, the input password needs to be verified with the encryption password. But not the plain input password, first you'll need to encrypt it with a salt and the `COOKIE_KEY` Then compare it with the one in the database using `password_verify()`